# Pulsing between two voltage distributions

Tags: rf

Consider a device with 3 electrodes.  By applying a known resistors chain across the electrodes we can have a known voltage on each electrode if the applied voltage is set correctly

[image: voltage drop over resistor chain]

Let’s say that I would like to alternatively pulse this to a different voltage distribution. My question is: how do I do this as the resistor chain is set?

I will be reversing the voltages during the pulse, therefore is it possible to use diodes to force the potential down a different resistor chain?

[image: two resistor chains]

I would like to do the pulsing at, say, 10 kHz and with high accuracy of the voltage, but even the lower-speed situation interests me.

Comment: It is possible but diodes will impede current and reduce voltage too.  Beware the capacitance inherent in your wires.  10kHz isn't too bad but certainly possible to screw up.

Comment: This sounds like an XY question; what are you using these voltages for?

Comment: Do you need an isolated voltage source, symmetric to GND or is this irrelevant?

Comment: I'd rather not say what it's for, it's a new invention.  I'm open to all ideas, the suggestion I gave was to help the conversation flow.

The relationship of the voltages to ground is unimportant.